# What do 'a' and 'c' stand for in 'Haversine formula' to measure the distance between two points?

Tags: distance, haversine, earthdistance

```
var R = 6371e3; // metres 
var φ1 = lat1.toRadians(); 
var φ2 = lat2.toRadians(); 
var Δφ = (lat2-lat1).toRadians();
 var Δλ = (lon2-lon1).toRadians(); 

var a = Math.sin(Δφ/2) * Math.sin(Δφ/2) + Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) * Math.sin(Δλ/2) * Math.sin(Δλ/2); 

var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 

var d = R * c;
```

Here in this code formula is used  in JavaScript. But anyway, there is a and c used in the original formula as well. What do they mean?

Comment: They're just temporary variables. Though `c` also appears to be actual the angle between the two points.

Comment: Have you taken a look at any of the trigonometric identities on Wikipedia? This looks like a trick is in play.

Comment: @Evert thanks. Both variables are being  used to measure  the angle right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, `c` is the angular distance between two points (in radians), and `a` is the square of half the chord length between two points.

P. S. See [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).